# Is there a pythonic way to add a file name to absolute path?

Tags: python, django

I am using `sqlite3` as my database for django. I am learning right now, so I wanted to know the best way of adding a file name to an already existing path. This example is from my django `settings.py` file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))  # Creating base directory
DB_NAME = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'database')                                    # Adding database name
if os.sep != '/':                                                               # For all cases (bullet-proofing)
    DB_NAME.replace(os.sep, '/')                                                # replacing
DB_NAME += (os.sep + 'sqlite3DB.db')                                            # Adding file name manually
```

What I simply did in order to add the name of the database file, is I simple added a `/` and the name of the file, which in this case is is `sqlite3DB.db`. I am doing this, because I am following the [django tutorial pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) at *Database Setup*. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? A more pythonic way, because it feels like I am hard-coding things. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have not created `sqlite3DB.db`, since in the tutorial it already says that it will be created for me by django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's you problem but you can use the `os.path.join` directly with the file name to produce the absolute path

```
os.path.join(DB_NAME, 'sqlite3DB.db')
```

Is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: Thanks, did not know this, now I feel sheepish. :P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really need . if its joining the file name with a path you have already mentioned it correctly

```
DB_NAME = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'database')
```

if its adding to system path then you can do something like this

```
import sys
sys.path = ['/opt/test/'] + sys.path
```

if you need to cd to the directory .. you could do something like this

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```